# Add a format to a HTML input tag

Tags: html, input

Is there any way to add a format to a input tag that the user has to use.
As an example I would like the user to input a text of the format:

int:int

or

2:1

Is there any way of doing this in html without writing a validation code in javascript?

Edit: I would be willing to use an extra library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to add an attribute `pattern=""` which uses Regex to validate the input format. In your case if you want any integer followed by ':' followed by other integer, the solution is:

```
<input pattern="\d+[:]\d+" title="{message_text}" />
```

Edit: added `title=""` attribute

Comment: Any way to change the message that pops up? And can you specify the maximum and minimum of these numbers?

Comment: you can change it by adding the `title="{message_text}"` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the quick help :)

Comment: regex is built for strings so checking for int values is a bit more complicated but not impossible, if you just want to limit the number of digits then replace the '+' character with '{MIN,MAX}', MIN and MAX should be min and max number of digits, if you want to have limit more specifically then you have to use the or operator for example if your upper limit is 400 the regex would be (400|[0-3][0-9][0-9]) where '|' is the or operator and '()' means that it has to be exactly in this case it would have to be '400' or any number starting with 0-3 followed by 0-9 followed by 0-9, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks :) a little hard to understand but figured it out

Comment: in case you don't specify the number of digits you have to remove \d but the rest its correct

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Vue.js by adding `v-model.numer=“”` in the html.  This would be using Vue, a external library that would handle it all for you.

For vanilla HTML, You can also use `type=“number”` in your input tag, and most browsers support this. The ones that don’t will default to type of text.  More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number